# Kendo Grid - pass over edited values in button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, kendo-grid

Im relatively new to javascript/jquery so forgive me if this sounds like a silly question.

I have a Kendo UI grid which is bound to a url from a controller method. This all works fine, but I want the user to be able to change the value on some of the fields. I have enabled the 'editable' flag on the table itself to allow these values to be changed, but when the button is clicked, it passes over the original value instead of the updated ones. Am i missing something simple?

```
    <div id="productlist-grid"></div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#productlist-grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                transport: {
                    read: { url: "@Html.Raw(dataUrl)", type: "POST", dataType: "json", data: additionalData }
                },
                schema: { data: "Data", total: "Total", errors: "Errors" },
                error: function(e) {
                    display_kendoui_grid_error(e);
                    // Cancel the changes
                    this.cancelChanges();
                },
                pageSize: @(defaultGridPageSize),
                serverPaging: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverSorting: true
            },
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: [@(gridPageSizes)]
            },
            editable: true,
            scrollable: false,
            columns:
            [
                {   field: "ProductPictureUrl", title: "Picture", template: '<img src="#=ProductPictureUrl#" />', width: 100, editable: false },
                {   field: "ProductName", title: "Product Name", editable: false },
                {   field: "ProductSku", title: "Sku", editable: false},
                {   field: "Quantity", title: "Quantity", type: "number"},
                {   field: 'SplitPack', title: 'Split Pack', template: kendo.template($("#template").html())},
                {   field: "AddToCart", title: "", template: '<a href="@Url.Action("AddToCart", "OrderTemplate")?ProductSku=#=ProductSku#&Quantity=#=Quantity#&TemplateId=@Model.TemplateId">Add To Cart</a>', editable: false}
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Many Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Take a look at the Kendo grid inline editing [demo](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline). I see that you have a `Read` method in your grid. But where is the `Create`, `Update` and `Destroy` methods?

Comment: Ideally I don't want to update the information on the server, as I want the defaults to remain as they are